# CollapsiblePanel unavailable

Tags: java, class, gwt

I found the very useful [`CollapsiblePanel` for Java GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/CollapsiblePanel.java?r=1723) on the net 
but in eclipse I'm unable to use it, it says that the class does not exist? I thought that it would be part of the GWT package?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Google Web Toolkit Incubator package. It has been deprecated though, as you may read here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/

Comment: So if CollapsiblePanel is deprecated is there any existing alternative  ?

Comment: If you would actually click the link provided above you could read there that "There is no replacement for CollapsiblePanel, but LayoutPanels allow you to create your own".